# How to get interface key type in generic function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a generic function that fetches some data:

```
function getData<T extends A | B | C>(initial: T[]): T[] {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ...some query
    setData(query result);

  }, []);

  return data;
}

interface A {
  someKeyA: string;
}

interface B {
  someKeyB: number;
}

interface C {
  someKeyC: A;
}
```

In another helper function for query i need to get key types of T. If initial data array is not empty i can do this and it works

```
const _key = typeof data[0].["someKeyA" as keyof T];
```

But sometimes initial data array is empty and then this fails because data[0] is undefined.

What i would need is to get K extends keyof T if there is no passed in data.
Is it possible to get typeof key from generic interface by key value or maybe create some temporary object with type T?

Comment: No, types do not exist at runtime (erased at compile time)

Comment: @AlekseyL.Ok, thought so but wasn't sure. Decided to hardcode some key values and defaulted rest.